# Microservice Architecture with NestJS + Kafka + Azure Function

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, azure-functions, microservices, nestjs

I am looking for some help with Architectural design for the Product I am working on.

I have chosen NestJS as my backend. Everything was working well when I was following Nestjs Documentation and working locally but now when am working with Azure (Azure function) I am finding it difficult to implement everything.

Here is the list of issues I am facing and I am sure someone new to Microservice and Azure might face the same issue.

1. I don't see any documentation for NestJS Microservice with Azure Function deployment. My microservices were earlier communicating with Kafka but after adding azure function to NestJS my Client application is unable to connect with my service.
2. I was initially working on docker but by the time I started with Azure Function, I did not find a document that explains well how to deploy a docker single container with azure function.
3. NestJS Monorepo architecture deployment with Azure. Though now I have changed to Polyrepo Structure but would have liked to continue with Monorepo.

These are the challenges that I am currently facing and working towards a solution but will really appreciate it if someone who has already gone through this can guide me or help me out with the solution. I will also make sure to update this question and solution in the near future so that no one else struggles with NestJS Microservice Architecture and Azure.

Comment: Is your application implemented as a Serverless service? Azure Functions is intended to be used with Serverless apps. 

As far as I now NestJS doesn't support Serverless architecture. If you indeed want to build a Microservice, then stick with docker, and perhaps change the hosting solution you are using.

Comment: @FirminoChangani I see think Nestjs is just another Nodejs framework. I am actually trying to use docker but it's quite hard at the moment.